# Why do I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when trying to run the Vertx server.js Hello world example?

Tags: javascript, vert.x

I've installed vertx and verified that it will run by asking for the version with gives

```
vertx version
2.1M3 (built 2014-01-17 14:33:50)
```

I then copied and pasted the sample server.js code from the install page which is supposed to generate a webpage that says "Hello world" when I go to the URL but instead I get 
No data received with and Chrome has ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for more details. (url is localhost:8080).  Verified that the firewall is (temporarily) off.

Answer (score 0):

After trying another example that used port 1234 and that one worked, changed the original Hello World example to port 1234 and the original example worked.  It appears I have another process running that is already using port 8080.  Now to go find out what that is.